# Would this be an accurate proverb towards IT security?

Tags: encryption

If encrypted by a computer so can be decrypted by a computer; the only two considerations are time and memory.

Comment: I don't fully understand the point you're making with that phrase - could you explain?

Comment: Let as explore this with an example: I have added two numbers, using a computer, to get 984575987947. What are the two numbers?

Answer (score 2):

It is right, but note: you have to differentiate between the practical and the theoretical possibilities.

If your attackers need $10^500$ clock cycles to decrypt your data, then the possibility of a crack is only theoretical. In practice, you have a much more chance that the crack happens because a software, hardware or theoretical fault in *your* systems, as anybody could crack it in the next billion years.